# How to test a class with anonymous listener that is set inside a function?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am just getting into unit testing on Android and I ran into some difficulties when I tried to test `bindTo()` function of this class.

```
class DataFlow<T> (produce: DataFlowProducer<T>): BaseDataFlow<T>(produce) {
    var updateOnAttach: Boolean = true

    fun bindTo(viewKontroller: ViewKontroller, updateImmediately: Boolean, updateUi: (data: T) -> Unit) {
        this.updateUi = updateUi
        if (updateImmediately)
            flow()
        viewKontroller.addLifecycleListener(object : Controller.LifecycleListener() {
            override fun postAttach(controller: Controller, view: View) {
                if (updateOnAttach) flow()
            }
            override fun preDestroyView(controller: Controller, view: View) {
                viewKontroller.removeLifecycleListener(this)
                this@DataFlow.updateUi = null
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If I mock my ViewKontroller test still crashes with NPE on line `viewKontroller.addLifecycleListener`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the test code would help

Comment: Sorry, don't have the code right now. But the main line in the test is basically `val dataflow = DataFlow { "test" }
dataflow.bindTo(mock(), true, { result = it })`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to check in the test is probably at least this:

1. `LifecycleListener` added to `ViewKontroller`
2. When `onPostAttach` is called by `ViewKontroller` something happens
3. When `preDestroyView` is called by `ViewKontroller` something else happens

So, the test double of `ViewKontroller` that you pass into constructor needs to "tell" you whether a listener was registered, and also to delegate method calls to that listener.

In such cases, when the test double object needs to have some actual functionality, it is best to implement a fake than using a mock.

In your case, just implement `FakeViewKontroller` that extends `ViewKontroller` and pass it to system under test instead of mock.

In that class you can expose additional methods that will allow you to ensure that `LifecycleListener` was added, and call methods on that listener in test cases.

Comment: Thank you! It is a very handy trick to use fake classes. But after thinking  about the code I guess it is just a bad implementation and `bindTo` should be a member function of ViewKontroller and lifecycle callbacks can be just functions in DataFlow which later can be easily tested.

Comment: Better design insights as a result of testing is what TDD is about ;)